# Create a relation

Tags: sql-server

I created the following tables and inserted few values.

```
create table books
(
bookid integer primary key, 
booktitle varchar(20), 
year integer, 
publisherid integer foreign key references publisher(publisherid), 
price integer,
number integer
)

create table publisher
(
publisherid integer primary key,
publishername varchar(20)
)

create table author
(
authorid integer primary key, 
authorname varchar(20)
) 

create table bookauthor
(
bookid integer foreign key references books(bookid),
authorid integer references author(authorid),
earnings integer
 ) 

create table bookreference
(
bookid integer foreign key references books(bookid),
referencebook varchar(20),
times integer
) 

create table reviewer
(
reviewerid integer primary key,
reviewername varchar(20)
) 

create table bookreview
(
bookid integer foreign key references books(bookid), 
reviewerid integer foreign key references reviewer(reviewerid),
score integer
)
```

Now, I want to solve following query in SQL Server 2000. Find all the books published in 2003 and reviewed by both ‘Sammer Tulpule’ and ‘Hemant Mahta’ . I am not getting any idea about query. How can I write it?

Thanks,
 Pooja

Comment: ‘Sammer Tulpule’ and ‘Hemant Mahta’  are values of which column and which table - be more specific

Comment: If you want to add additional information to your question, please just edit your question. Kindly, do not post clarification as an answer, answers are reserved for answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.bookid as bookid
FROM (books b INNER JOIN bookreview br ON (br.bookid=b.bookid)) 
         INNER JOIN reviewer r ON (br.reviewerid = r.reviewerid)
WHERE year=2003 AND r.reviewername IN ('Sammer Tulpule', 'Hemant Mahta')
GROUP BY b.bookid
HAVING COUNT(r.reviewerid) >= 2
```

Obviously, this is assuming that you don't have duplicated entries in the bookreview table.

Comment: She want's for the case where a book has been reviewed by both and not either or. So r.reviewername IN ('Sammer Tulpule', 'Hemant Mahta') wont work

Comment: @Varun, u r right. I know i am asking whole queries, i believe me i am very new to sql server and really don't know how to write that queries. I ran the query suggested by  Stephen Chung, but it doesn't shows any output, only shows column name i.e. 'bookid'.

Comment: @Pooja, do it one step at a time.  Try it without the GROUP BY clause and the HAVING clause (and add some more fields in the SELECT clause) to see if you are successfully joining the two reviewers.  Then put in the GROUP BY and the COUNT clause in the SELECT to see if the count is correct.  Finally put the HAVING clause in.  This is the way to debug SQL queries.

Comment: @Pooja, one more point.  I don't think it is your knowledge of SQL Server that is the issue.  You should not need to use any proprietary SQL Server features for your query, only standard SQL.  So you'll need to brush up on your SQL skills instead.  Try building the query one piece at a time, and one JOIN at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT b.* FROM books b, bookreview br, reviewer rv WHERE b.year = 2003 AND br.bookid = b.bookid and br.reviewerid = rv.reviewerid and rv.reviewername = 'Sammer Tulpule') 
INTERSECT
(SELECT b.* FROM books b, bookreview br, reviewer rv WHERE b.year = 2003 AND br.bookid = b.bookid and br.reviewerid = rv.reviewerid and rv.reviewername = 'Hemant Mahta')
```

I am typing this on the fly so there might be small errors, but you get the general idea...

Comment: INTERSECT is only available from Sql Server 2005+ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Agreed, this is simple to understand though... so leaving it here.... I didn't know people were STILL using SQL server 2000!!!

Comment: You can leave it here, but it does not help the OP. So dont be alarmed when you get some downvotes.

Comment: actually.....sql server 2005 is not ready to install on my pc, thats why i am using 2000. And i ran your query, it doesn't support 'intersect' keyword.